# Setting up UserForm elements for unique validation

Tags: vba, excel

This is a continuation of a previous question regarding the specific validation of textboxes in an Excel UseForm. [**Sorceri**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1586390/sorceri) helped me a lot with getting this code, but I'm now needing some fine-tuning. I need to validate differently across different textboxes. I've built the textboxes via the "Controls" in the "Toolbox." They named sequentially as such; "info1", "info2", "info3", and so forth.

The validation for most of the textboxes can be seen below ("1-5", "88", and "99"). Two of the textboxes, however, need to be validated differently ("1-3" and "88"). In addition to this, there needs to be a third validation set for a third group of textboxes ("0-10" and "88"). I'm fairly new to VBA and programming in general, but I'm quick learner. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To add clarification, I added my own commentary next to Sorceri's in parentheses. Thanks again, everyone.

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    'check to see if it is a textbox (I'm guessing I could specify which textboxes here, but I'm unsure)
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        Dim tBox As MSForms.TextBox
        Set tBox = ctl
        'we have a textbox so validate the entry (Again, I'm hoping to make this into, "We found textbox variant A and so will validate its entry with validation A, etc)
        If validateTextBox(tBox) Then
            'did not validate so set focus on the control
            MsgBox "Invalid Entry!", vbCritical, "Invalid!"
            ctl.SetFocus
            'release the object
            Set tBox = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set tBox = Nothing
    End If
Next
End Sub




'validate a textbox's value and return true or false
Private Function validateTextBox(tb As MSForms.TextBox) As Boolean
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim bInvalid As Boolean
    bInvalid = True
    sValue = Trim(tb.Text)
    If sValue = "1" Or sValue = "2" Or sValue = "3" Or sValue = "4" Or sValue = "5" Or sValue = "99" Or sValue = "88" Then
        bInvalid = False
    End If
    'return the results
    validateTextBox = bInvalid
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the real issue is how your textbox elements are grouped.  There needs to be some way to distinguish between the three different groups that need validating.  The easiest way may be a naming convention to append to each textbox's name current name  (unless you can use grouping controls IE Frames).  You can go with A-B-C or really any other naming scheme.  I am going to go with the A-B-C in this example.

Group A validates
("1-5", "88", and "99")

Group B validates
("1-3" and "88")

Group C validates
("0-10" and "88")

now at the end of each textBox I append an A, B, or C to distinguish wich group the textbox belongs to. You stated that your textbox elements follow this naming scheme: "info1", "info2", "info3",

so we sould now have "info1A", "info2A", "info3C", "info4B", "info5C".... "info30A",

with this we now add an Enumeration type for each group

```
Private Enum ValidationGroup
NONE
A 
B
C
End Enum
```

'we will add a switch statement to the method for getting the group

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    'check to see if it is a textbox
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        Dim tBox As MSForms.TextBox
        Dim tbGroup As ValidationGroup

        Set tBox = ctl
        'we have a textbox so check the group and validate the entry
        'get the group to validate against
        tbGroup = Switch(Right(tBox.Name, 1) = "A", ValidationGroup.A, _
        Right(tBox.Name, 1) = "B", ValidationGroup.B, _
        Right(tBox.Name, 1) = "C", ValidationGroup.C, _
        Right(tBox.Name, 1) <> "*", ValidationGroup.NONE) 'default value of none

        If validateTextBox(tBox, tbGroup ) Then
            'did not validate so set focus on the control
            MsgBox "Invalid Entry!", vbCritical, "Invalid!"
            ctl.SetFocus
            'release the object
            Set tBox = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set tBox = Nothing 
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

change the validateTextBox to include the enum

**as a side note this method could be overhauled to be more efficient

```
'validate a textbox's value and return true or false
Private Function validateTextBox(tb As MSForms.TextBox, vg As ValidationGroup) As Boolean
    Dim sValue As String
    Dim bInvalid As Boolean
    bInvalid = True
    sValue = Trim(tb.Text)t
    'check the validation group then check the values
    If vg = ValidationGroup.A Then
        If sValue = "1" Or sValue = "2" Or sValue = "3" Or sValue = "4" Or sValue = "5" Or sValue = "99" Or sValue = "88" Then
            bInvalid = False
        End If
    ElseIf vg = ValidationGroup.B Then
        If sValue = "1" Or sValue = "2" Or sValue = "3" Or sValue = "88" Then
            bInvalid = False
        End If
    ElseIf vg = ValidationGroup.C Then
        If sValue = "0" Or sValue = "1" Or sValue = "2" Or sValue = "3" Or sValue = "4" Or sValue = "5" Or _
        sValue = "6" Or sValue = "7" Or sValue = "8" Or sValue = "9" Or sValue = "10" Or sValue = "88" Then
            bInvalid = False
        End If
    End If
    'return the results
    validateTextBox = bInvalid
End Function
```

Comment: Everyone's input has been helpful, but I think I'm going to try and work with this. This looks great. I'll be back should I run into any trouble, but thanks again for all the help, @Sorceri.

Comment: So I've copied-and-pasted this but when I run the UserForm, I will still receive the invalid message box even when all entries are valid. I've renamed my TextBoxes accordingly. If I need to make a third question, I  can, but I wanted to ask you first before flooding the forum again.

Comment: Are there any textboxes on the form that do not need validating?

Comment: For now, yes. There are two "comment" boxes that need to be entered verbatim. Should I add a fourth modifier to their TextBox labels?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the condition to account for those else it will default to the not validated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below.

I placed some select cases in your Function based on the name of the text box.

I assumed, for simplicity, you would (re-)name your text boxes based on the validation grouping. However, you could put each individual textbox names in the `Case Is =` statement and get rid of the `Left` function in the `Select Case` statement.

I also changed the `tb.Value` to `Integer` to make the If statements easer to write / read.

This isn't meant to be a full-proof answer as much as it is to give a clear construct upon which to build your answer.

```
Function validateTextBox(tb As MSForms.TextBox) As Boolean

    Dim iValue As Integer, sName As String, bInvalid As Boolean

    bInvalid = True

    sName = tb.Name
    iValue = CInt(Trim(tb.Text))

    If iValue = 88 Then 'because this is common among all the groups check for it first

        bInvalid = False

    Else

        Select Case Left(sName, "4")

            Case Is = "grp1"

                If (iValue > 1 And iValue <= 5) Or iValue = 99 Then bInvalid = False

            Case Is = "grp2"

                If (iValue > 1 And iValue <= 3) Then bInvalid = False

            Case Is = "grp3"

                If (iValue > 1 And iValue <= 10) Then bInvalid = False

        End Select

    End If

    'return the results
    validateTextBox = bInvalid

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your validation values in each Textbox's `Tag` property like this "1-30,88,89" (no quotes though)  Might want to tidy up those variable declarations a bit too.

```
Function ValidateTextBox(tb As MSForms.TextBox) As Boolean
    Dim sTag, i, arr, arrVal, min, max, v, tbVal, ok As Boolean

    tbVal = Trim(tb.Value)

    If IsNumeric(tbVal) Then

        sTag = Replace(tb.Tag, " ", "") 'remove any spaces from tb Tag

        v = CInt(tbVal) 'convert the textbox value to integer

        If sTag <> "" Then
            arr = Split(sTag, ",")
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                arrVal = Trim(arr(i))
                If InStr(arrVal, "-") > 0 Then
                    'check against a range
                    min = CInt(Split(arrVal, "-")(0))
                    max = CInt(Split(arrVal, "-")(1))
                    If v >= min And v <= max Then
                        ok = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Else
                   'just a single value to check against
                   If v = CInt(arr(i)) Then
                        ok = True
                        Exit For
                   End If
                End If
            Next i
        Else
            MsgBox "No rule for this textbox: " & tb.Name
        End If

    End If

    ValidateTextBox = ok

End Function
```